# many Datpickers with same class getDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've got a question, got couple of input datepickers like

```
<input name="datepicker_one" class="datepicker" readonly type="text" value="12-12-2013" />
<input name="datepicker_two" class="datepicker" readonly type="text" value="13-12-2013" />
<input name="datepicker_three" class="datepicker" readonly type="text" value="14-12-2013" />
```

and I'm trying to get values of clicked datepicker, while trying to avoid writing different methods for each of those inputs, so I wonder if there is a way to get datepicker value just by clicking on input with class .datepicker like:

```
$(".datepicker").click(function(e){ $(this).val(); });
```

but this gives me undefined value also:

```
$(".datepicker").click(function(e){ $(this).datepicker("getDate"); });
```

Does not seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using your value. The statment:

```
$(this).val();
```

Is meaningless as it doesn't do anything. You get the value, but didn't use it. If you did

```
console.log($(this).val());
```

you would actually see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $(".datepicker").click(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
        return false;
    });
```